# BorderLayout.Center is not working with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

```
public class BorLay 
{

  BorLay()
  {
      JFrame frame=new JFrame("Connect");
      JPanel panel=new JPanel();
       frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       panel.add(new JTextField("Click1"));
       panel.add(new JTextField("Click2"));
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setSize(400,500);

  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      new BorLay();
  }
}
```

[image]

Above code is not working when JPanel is added to JFrame .But if JTextField is directly add to JFrame it is wokring.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ? The posted code should show two text fields.

Comment: But both should be in Center of the Frame .

Comment: Agree with @c0der, the GUI you show is exactly what I'd expect from the code. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson both the textfield are BorderLayout.NORTH but i want them to be in Center .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain _not working_" . The layout is ex erected. Please review https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Comment: @SiddharthTeli the components are not in BorderLayout.NORTH. Simply  BorderLayout.NORTH` is empty

Comment: *But why BorderLayout.Center doesn't work with JPanel* - CENTER just means the entire component will occupy the space available in the frame. It does not imply that the components will be centered horizontally and vertically in the frame. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout. The FlowLayout, by default, will display components centered horizontally. That can be changed to have the components left aligned or right aligned. However, the components will always be display at the top of the panel.

Comment: *but works fine when components are directly added to frame .* - not possible. For one thing you can only add a single component to the CENTER of the BorderLayout. In that cause the entire component is sized to fill all the space available. So if you add a JButton, then the button will fill the entire space. If you add a JLabel, then yes, the text might appear centered because the JLabel has properties that allow you to configure how the text is painted when the size of the label is greater than the size of the text.

Comment: @camickr,If i add a component like JButton to Frame & use BorderLayout.CENTER then the component will be in center of the frame .But if i add a component to a JPanel then use BorderLayout.CENTER like frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER) it doesn't work & component is either on SOUTH or WEST but not in CENTER .EVEN if i use setHorizontalAlignment & setVerticalAlignment still the component would  not be on Center .By the way thanks to everyone I used GridBagLayout & now result is as expected .

Comment: (1-) @SiddharthTeli *If i add a component like JButton to Frame & use BorderLayout.CENTER then the component will be in center of the frame* - If all you have is a frame and you add a button to the frame, then no it will NOT be centered in the frame. I have told you this and Andrew has told you this. The button will be sized to fill the entire frame. This does NOT make is centered. "centered" means the component is displayed at its preferred size AND the component is in centered vertically and horizontally within the frame. Post your [mre] that demonstrates your claim.

Answer (score 1):

To center the panel containing the text fields, add it to a **`GridBagLayout`.**

[image]

The red border shows how the panel which contains them is not made bigger to fill the parent container (the content pane).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BorLay {

    BorLay() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Connect");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(new JTextField("Click1"));
        panel.add(new JTextField("Click2"));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200, 100); // make bigger as per need
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new BorLay();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .But why BorderLayout.Center doesn't work with JPanel but works fine when components are directly added to frame .

Comment: *"but works fine when components are directly added to frame"* I don't see how that could work. Can you produce code that replicates the effect? And this time, please include the imports to make testing easier. BTW - see edit to answer. If you're having unusual results from a layout, I recommend adding a visible border to the components in question. It can be very illuminating.